# How can I integrate an online compiler in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am working on this site using drupal and one of the things I need to accomplish is to accept code from the user and if possible compile it and accept?
Is there a way to achieve this in drupal?

Comment: It is not recommended to execute user content on your server (unless you are a security wizard).

Comment: What he said. Also, it may help to know what language you're looking to compile? And if you're only confused on the Drupal side of it, it may be better to ask the question on drupal.stackexchange.com

Comment: You have no where near enough detail in your question to give you a decent answer. I suggest you fix your question if you expect a good answer.